# Treat MSBuild exec task timeout as an error

Tags: msbuild

I'm specifying a timeout for an MSBuild Exec task like this:

```
<Exec Command="MyCommand.bat" Timeout="3000" />
```

If my command times out, MSBuild issues a warning. I would like it to instead issue an error that fails the build. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [OnError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164285.aspx) element and the [Error Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx):

```
<Target Name="ExecCommand">
        <Exec Command="MyCommand.bat" Timeout="3000" />
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="TimeoutErrorHandler"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="TimeoutErrorHandler">
    <Error Text="Command timeout"/>
</Target>
```