# MSBuild - Deploying a Windows Service Automatically after building

Tags: powershell, msbuild, windows-services, continuous-integration

Ok, this is what I want to do -

We have a windows service and we want to automate deployment of this service to the test environments after every successful CI build - for this we thought of the following approach -

- Build the Windows Service project (along with dependencies)
- Stop the windows service
- Copy the project output from the output folder to the Windows Service file-path
- Start the service

However, currently I am facing problems with the starting and stopping of the windows service.

This is the MSBuild snippet -

```
<!-- TODO: do this using Powershell instead of normal commandline so that it can be executed on remote machines as well -->
<Exec Command="Net Stop CreditProcessing" />
<!-- Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NoProfile -Noninteractive -command &quot;&amp;{ Stop-Service CreditProcessing }&quot;" /-->

<!-- TODO: The destination needs to come from the env variable or rsp file? -->
<Copy 
    SourceFiles="@(WindowsServiceFilesToDeploy)" 
    DestinationFiles="@(WindowsServiceFilesToDeploy->'D:\WindowsServices\Credit Processing Service%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />  

<Exec Command="Net Start CreditProcessing" />   
<!--Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NoProfile -Noninteractive -command Start-Service CreditProcessing" /-->
```

This I tried with both direct command line commands as well as powershell commands.

A) This is the problem I face when I try to run this build with normal commands - the service takes some time to start/stop and the build doesn't wait long enough and reports an error and stops

"... service could not be started".
"Service did not report an error"

or sometimes when stopping

"The service could not be controlled in its present state."

whereas if we immediately check the services it will be in "Starting" stage and soon it will go to "Start" stage. Any way to make the build be a little more patient? The command doesn't do this if run directly from command prompt.

B) This is the problem we face if I use the above powershell commands (currently commented in the snippet) -

It just opens the powershell prompt in the build log and then just does nothing
[image: Build stops at powershell doesn't continue]

Can you help avoid these problems (at least one of these)? I think the powershell route is more recommended if it works fine, but I'm open to suggestions.

A couple of other questions -

- We want to deploy the service (and hence stop and restart) on a remote machine (other than where this CI build is happening) - anyway this can be done?
- Is there a way to add a check whether the service is already running and stop only if it is running? If it is stopped and we try to stop again, it will give "Service not started" error

Comment: Can you post how you're defining $(PowerShell)? Peering at the screenshot, it seems as if it's injecting a newline after the path to powershell.exe. This could explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Yes! that was it!! @JohnL Can you put this as an answer so that I can upvote and mark it?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command to launch is of this form:

```
path\to\powershell.exe
-arg1 -arg2
```

The newline means that PowerShell never receives the arguments, so doesn't know it has to execute a `Start-Service` command, and doesn't know you don't want it to be interactive.  It's probably just waiting for you to tell it what to do.

Check your $(PowerShell) variable, as it probably has a newline at the end.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the problem was.. had put the close tag on the next line without realizing it's seen as a newline.

Answer (score 1):

why not use [sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192/en-us) which has native remote capabilities ?

Comment: Thats an interesting possibility - I just tried it though and it doesn't wait for the Service to start/stop - I would still like the build to fail if it faces a genuine problem in stopping/starting - is that possible with sc.exe?

Comment: Also the build needs to wait till the service stop before copying the files

Comment: Ok, an update - I tried with the /wait flag for the stop/start command "start /wait sc stop creditprocessing" - it again gives the same problem as A) above (build doesn't wait long enough and simply errors out)

Comment: Cant you add a pause using start-sleep?

Comment: it's the step itself that times out - pause not helping

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy From your other comment I guess you managed to get this sorted, but FYI, `<Exec>` has a `Timeout` property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123702/treat-msbuild-exec-task-timeout-as-an-error

Comment: @JohnL - yes that's correct - I tried that now, it works sometimes, but sometimes it just waits and doesn't return - in fact if I see the service status it shows stopped but the build just waits it out till the timeout occurs and then gives an error. I have no idea why it doesnt get intimated that the service has stopped. Anyways I would give you one more upvote if I could, however for now the powershell option works great for me!